# if $ A $ is matrix, $ T $ is a linear operator, $ f $ is a polynomial and $ f(T)(A)=0 $ for every matrix A. Can we conclude that f(T)=0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So the original problem was:

Let $ V=M_n(F) $ be a vector space of matrices. And $ T: V \rightarrow V $ defined by T(A)=BA for some matrix $ B \in V $

prove that the minimal polymonial of B is the same as the mininal of the operator T.

So i managed to show that for every polynomial $ f \in F[x] $

if $ f(T)=0 $ then for every matrix A

$ f(B)A=0 $ and thus $ f(B) $  is the zero matrix. And I managed to show that if $ f(B)=0 $ then for every matrix A

$ f(T)(A)=0 $ but i cant convince myself that $ f(T) $ is the zero operator. Can we even conclude such thing? Thanks.

Comment: a map $M$ is defined by $M(A)$ for every element $A$ in its domain. So if the map $f(T)$ maps every $A \in M_n (F)$ to $0$, what does that mean for the map $f(T)$?

Comment: @Targon I guess it means that the map is the zero map, but for example, if i'll take the polymonial $ f=x^2 +x$ over the field $ \mathbb{Z}mod2 $ then for every $ \alpha \in Zmod2 $  $ f(\alpha)=0 $ but f is not the zero polynomial

Comment: But you are asking whether $f(T)=0$, not whether $f=0$.

Comment: I know but if for polynomials $ f(x)=0 $ for every x dosent gurantee that f=0  then why for some random linear operator it does gurantee?

Comment: @Waizman The situation with polynomials is tricky when $x$ is an [indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)). In the statement "$f(T) = 0$," $T$ is not an indeterminate. Rather, $T$ is a specific operator defined in the beginning of the problem, and $f(T)$ is another operator.